# How to find the tangent cone to an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, ellipsoids

Is there a standard way to find the tangent cone to a general ellipsoid from a point outside of the ellipsoid?

Answer (score 2):

$\def\x{\mathbf{x}}$
$\def\u{\mathbf{u}}$

**Special case:** For conics whose center is at the origin see [Armstrong, *Where is the cone?*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.07093.pdf), Section 4.

Specifically, if the ellipsoid is defined as

$$\x^T A\x =1,$$

the paper shows that the tangent cone from $\u$ to the surface $\x^TA\x=1$ has the equation
$$
\begin{equation*}
\boxed{(\x^TA\u-1)^2=(\x^TA\x-1)(\u^TA\u-1).}
\end{equation*}
$$

**General case:** If the conic is not centered at the origin, see [Bobenko et al](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.00978.pdf), pg 17, Def 3.1.

For a symmetric matrix $Q$, and $\x,\u$ in homogeneous form, the tangent cone from $\u$ to the quadric
$\x^TQ\x=0$ is given by

$$
(\x^TQ\u)^2-(\x^TQ\x)(\u^TQ\u)=0. 
$$

The special case uses a $3\times3$ matrix $A$, while the general case uses a $4\times4$ matrix $Q$, so arguably one could just use the general formula in all cases.